# Grouping articles based on category on the same page in Gatsby JS

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I have a Gatsby JS website and I would like to display on the same page a list of articles grouped by 'families' (categories, basically).

Here's what I did so far:

```
...

{edges.map(({ node }) => {

              let families = []
              _.each(edges, edge => {
                  if (_.get(edge, "node.frontmatter.family")) {
                      families = families.concat(node.frontmatter.family)
                  }
              })

              _.forEach(family => {
                  const articlesinfamily = () => {
                      return edges.filter(edge => edge.node.frontmatter.family === family)
                  }

           return (
                  <>
                  <div className="column is-3">
                    <div className="content">
                      <div className="title is-3">
                          {family}
                      </div>
                      <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column is-9">

                    <div className="columns is-multiline">
                      {articlesinfamily.map(({ node }) => {
                        <div className="column is-4">
                          <div className="content">
                            <div className="title is-4">
                                {node.frontmatter.name}
                            </div>
                            <p>{node.frontmatter.headline}</p>     

                           </div>
                         </div>
                      })}

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </>   
                )
              })
          })}



...
```

This code doesn't work but I think it's the closest I've come to a solution.
The error I get is

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

on the line where I have {articlesinfamily.map(({ node }) => {....

Any clue on how to make this work? Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use lodash _.groupBy method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error you had in your initial question:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

...means that this expression inside your `map`:

```
{articlesinfamily.map(({ node }) => {
  <div className="column is-4">
    <div className="content">
      <div className="title is-4">
        {node.frontmatter.name}
      </div>
      <p>{node.frontmatter.headline}</p>     
    </div>
  </div>
})}
```

...is effectively not being used. You are not assigning it to any variables, nor calling a function.

The solution here, as you have found in the answer you posted, is to **return the expression** (therefore using it in a function):

```
{articlesinfamily.map(({ node }) => {
  return (
    <div className="column is-4">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="title is-4">
          {node.frontmatter.name}
        </div>
        <p>{node.frontmatter.headline}</p>     
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

You can also use a more concise [**implicit return**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) by swapping your curly brackets for parentheses:

```
{articlesinfamily.map(({ node }) => (
  <div className="column is-4">
    <div className="content">
      <div className="title is-4">
        {node.frontmatter.name}
      </div>
      <p>{node.frontmatter.headline}</p>     
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a very embarrassing mistake, not returning the expression :)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, this is how we learn :) Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I solved this using Graphql 'group', like this:

Query page:

```
export const updatesQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark( filter: {  frontmatter: { contentType: { eq: "updates" } } } ) {
      group(field: frontmatter___family) {
        fieldValue
        totalCount
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              name
              headline
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And then in the page component I used group.map() first, and then edges.map() to catch all the 'content' inside a group. Like so:

```
...

        {data.allMarkdownRemark.group.map(( { fieldValue, edges } ) => {

               return (

                  <>
                  <div className="column is-3">
                    <div className="content">
                      <div className="title">
                          {fieldValue}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column is-1"></div>
                  <div className="column is-8">

                      <div className="columns is-multiline">

                          {edges.map(( { node } ) => {

                            return (

                              <div className="column is-4">
                                <div className="content">
                                    <div className="title">{node.frontmatter.name}</div>
                                    <p>{node.frontmatter.headline}</p>     

                                </div>
                              </div>

                            )    
                          })}

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </>   
               )    
          })}

...
```

Hope this helps you as well.

Comment: Good job for solving it by yourself! The key thing here is that you returned the expression on the line where the error from your question happened. See my answer for details :)